Laravel Process Facade not Returning Python Requests ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")
I'm dealing with such an odd issue here. I'm attempting to run a python script in my laravel app using Process facade and the python script is doing a simple status 200 return on google. (playing around with Process in general).
But I'm unable to get any response whenever I use the facade to run the script, while any other simple script (like a hello world Python Script) returns just fine. Could there be some issue with the Request Library? Or is it some network stuff that is the issue?
I'm also able to get a status 200 when I run the script through command line.
I'm running my laravel app locally btw.
This is a simple Laravel Process I'm passing. I don't think I even need the path
public function ubuntu()
{

    $pythonFolder = $this->pythonFolderPath;
    $pythonProgram = $this->pythonProgram;
    
    $result = process::path($pythonFolder)->run([$pythonProgram, 'ConnectToGoogle.py']);
    

    return $result->output();
}

This is the python script I am testing on. It should be a simple Request connecting to Google
import requests

def check_google_connection():
    # URL of Google's homepage
    url = "https://www.google.com/"

    try:
        # Send a GET request to the URL
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        # Check if the status code is 200
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Successfully connected to Google's homepage.")
            print(f"Status code: {response.status_code}")
            return True
        else:
            print(f"Connection failed. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            return False

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while connecting to Google: {e}")
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_google_connection()

[This is the response when I run the Python Script through Laravel Process Facade]
"An error occurred while connecting to Google: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NameResolutionError(": Failed to resolve 'www.google.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))"
Any general direction on how to wrap my head around is appriciated.
I've attempted to use env() to change the environemnt and even ran the python script in a virtual enviroment. Nothing seems to change.

General direction: Don't post code as links nor pictures.
